# selecting top 3 values (based on their count) from each category

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get the top 3 rows from col2 for each letter in col1 based on the count of col2

My table looks like this:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 4 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |

So for example, here I have that A=1 one time, A=2 three times and A=3 two times (similar for B).

I would like my output to look like this:

| col1 | col2 | count(col2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| A | 3 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| B | 4 | 1 |

Where it shows me the top 3 values (col2) (based on the count) of A for col1. Same for B.

I figured out how to do the SQL query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, x 
FROM (SELECT col1, col2, count(col2) AS x, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY count(col2) DESC) AS rn 
FROM data 
GROUP BY col1, col2) tmp 
WHERE rn <= 3 
ORDER BY col1
```

But now I need to do the same using dataframes. I'm trying to do this but it's not giving me the output that I want (see above):

```
df.withColumn("rank",dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("col1"))
  .filter(col("rank")<=3)
  .groupby(col1,col2)
  .agg(first("col2"))
  .show()
```

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
df.groupBy("col1","col2").count()
.withColumn("rank",rank().over(Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy(desc("count"))))
.where("rank <= 3")
.show()
```

It shows me the count of col 2 but from biggest to smallest yet it is still not what I want as it shows me all the rows when I only want the top three for each group in col1.

Ideas?

Comment: You're going to want to use nested Selects here because SQL does not perform operations like you want.   The Window functions like Row_Number() are performed dead last WAY after your Where clause.  Inner Select should create a column that counts occurrences with a Group By and adds a Rank() over or row_number() over function based on that count.  Your outer SQL can select out only the columns you want to preserve and also uses Where rank_col<=3.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT col1,col2
FROM (
    SELECT col1,col2,
           row_number() over(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY cnt DESC) as rn
    FROM (
        SELECT col1,col2,COUNT(1) as cnt 
        FROM `table`
        group by col1,col2
    ) t0
) t1
WHERE rn <= 3
```

Comment: UPDATE: I tried this but it didn't work, thanks though. I think I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

in PySpark:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('A','1')
    ,('B','2')
    ,('A','2')
    ,('B','2')
    ,('B','1')
    ,('B','1')
    ,('B','1')
    ,('A','3')
    ,('A','2')
    ,('B','4')
    ,('A','2')
    ,('B','2')
    ,('A','3')
    ,('A','4')
    ],
    ['col1','col2']
)

from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy('col2')

df\
    .withColumn('rank', F.dense_rank().over(w))\
    .filter(F.col('rank')<=3)\
    .groupby('col1','col2')\
    .agg(F.first('col2').alias('dummy'))\
    .drop('rank','dummy')\
    .show()

# +----+----+
# |col1|col2|
# +----+----+
# |   A|   1|
# |   A|   2|
# |   A|   3|
# |   B|   1|
# |   B|   2|
# |   B|   4|
# +----+----+
```

Comment: Hi Luiz, thank you but this is not quite I need. I col2 to show the count not the rank. How can I do that?

Comment: UPDATE: I figured it out using df. I basically do something like: df.groupBy(col1, col2).count().withColumn("row", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(col1).orderBy(desc("count")))).where("row <= 3")